# Product variants through External API

Tags: odoo, product, odoo-8, odoo-12

I am trying to create product variants through Odoo external API, however, I stuck. I have created already attributes and attribute values. So, product prices are varying based on the attributes. I need to create several product variants with different prices. However, I am not able to do it through API.

```
add_product = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template', 'create', [{
    'name': "Table", 'categ_id': 1, 'attribute_id': 20, 'attribute_value_id':  2,'company_id': 1, 'list_price': '225', 'standard_price': '125', 'type': 'consu'
}])
```

[image]

Anybody came across with the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
attribute_line = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'product.template.attribute.line', 'create',[{'product_tmpl_id':47,'attribute_id':375,'value_ids':[(6,False,[23])]}])
```

This worked out